# Python argparse version: Newlines not respected

Tags: python, argparse

Python's [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module allows explicit the specification of a version. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to respect newlines in the output:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")

parser.add_argument("--version", "-v", action="version", version="some\ntext")

parser.parse_args()
```

```
python3 a.py -v
```

```
some text
```

Any hints on how to work around this?

Comment: If you want a different format, have you tried changing the formatter? https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`RawTextHelpFormatter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter):

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="test", formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
)
```

You should know that this formatter will affect every argument and not just the `version`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom Action if you want to do something very specific with the version output:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

class VersionAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, version=None, **kwargs):
        super(VersionAction, self).__init__(option_strings, nargs=0, help="show program's version number and exit", **kwargs)
        self.version = version
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print('%s' % self.version)
        exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="args")
    parser.add_argument("--version", "-v", action=VersionAction, version="some\ntext")

    parser.parse_args()
```

Also, this only changes you `-v` option and does not affect your other options.